# How to tell, which coefficient corresponds to which frequency while computing wavelet transform?

Tags: signal-analysis, wavelet, time-frequency

I am applying wavelet transform on [functional Near Infrared Spectroscopy (fNIRS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_near-infrared_spectroscopy) signal.

My aim is to get the info that which coefficient corresponds to which frequency in the signal. Is it possible to do so, moreover if there can be some other way please mention it.

Comment: wavelets are kind of a hybrid time-localized / non-localized frequency estimator. Are you sure you want to use wavelets if you actually want to know freqeuncy? That sounds like a job for the DFT.

Comment: What if I want to do it using wavelet transform only. Is there any way sir?@MarcusMüller

Comment: Why would you want to use a tool that's giving you a different result than what you need? (That's an honest question, when you say "you want", I assume you have a technical reason.)

Comment: I know I can do this using FT

Comment: yes, but what's the reason not to? You got to have a reason, because when you look at the FT, it's nothing but the actual projection of your signal onto "prototype" frequency signals; i.e. there **can't** be an integral transform that is any more optimal for harmonic frequency than the FT, so by choosing to use wavelets, you're actively doing something worse in terms of estimating frequencies. So, what's your **reason** for using wavelets? From that, we can infer what you'd want to do to reach your goal.

Comment: I know I can do this using FT but thing is I just want to know how WT coefficients corresponds to the frequencies or what information these coefficients deliver. I have seen some literature where people have used WT to denoise signals by making the coefficients of noise zero and then taking inverse WT  to get a noise free signal. This is the reason.

Comment: But if noise can be reduced by setting a specific discrete wavelet coefficient zero, that means that the noise maps to the wavelet space, not to frequency space – the whole point of wavelets is that they are not "single-frequency". So, I don't think your question can be answered – the wavelet family that maps one wavelet coefficient to a frequency **is** the DFT.

Comment: Does this mean it is impossible to link coefficients to the frequencies?

Comment: Well, take your discrete Wavelet base functions, and DFT them; then you know which wavelet has which frequency content.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do you think you could turn this into an answer? Then we can gracefully close this question. Warrad the "mapping" is as mentioned by MM with the addition of course of the "forced" scaling that comes in effect because of successive decimations. There is more information in [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/scal2frq.html), but I think too that the points raised by MM are valid in your context. This "mapping" is not exactly straightforward.

Comment: @A_A Thanks for responding to my question, I am familiar with this mapping but it gives pseudo frequencies so I am feeling reluctance in using it.

Comment: Given a wavelet, how do you define "pseudofrequency"? What would be a better definition of its central frequency (at some given scale)? How does this transform not fitting the problem you are faced with?